# Read excel file and insert records in database in C#- Windows Azure

Tags: c#, excel, azure

The requirements for my application is to browse for an excel file, Upload the file , read each row from the excel file and insert into the database.

I am building this application in Windows Azure. 
Prior to this I have successfully used `OleDbDataAdapter` to read the data from the excel file into the `dataset`.

The connection strings I used are:

FOR XLS file:

```
connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strNewPath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2"""
```

FOR XLSX file:

```
connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strNewPath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2"""
```

Will the following providers `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` & `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` be avaialable in Windows Azure?
Will approach also work in Cloud as well and is this the best way to access Excel files in c#?

Any new ideas and suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, OLE providers will not be available under the Worker Role by default. It might be possible to have them later in a different VM setup though.

For the time being you are basically restricted to .NET-only options:

- [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) for XLSX
- [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) for XLS

Answer (score 1):

I am using OpenXMl SDK for excel processing. It works perfectly in cloud environment.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned you need to support .xls and .xlsx files, you could use a product like [OfficeWriter](http://www.officewriter.com) which supports both file types in one library.

Disclaimer: I am one of the developers on OfficeWriter