# Getting an 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine error when I tried hosting on Azure Servers

Tags: azure, oledb

I am hosting a web application which uses OLEDB 12 to read an Excel file, but getting the error "'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine". Wonder if I should use lower version of OLEDB or Azure does not support OLEDB services at all. Before rewriting the program, just wanted to see if anyone knows a better alternative. I am using Visual Studio 2010 for my development.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read excel file and insert records in database in C#- Windows Azure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663245/read-excel-file-and-insert-records-in-database-in-c-windows-azure)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238625/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered)