# Cannot upload excel file on azure website

Tags: excel, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am having trouble while uploading excel file on Azure website.

The **error** I keep getting is

> Azure - 'Microsoft.ACE.OleDb.12.0' provider is not registered on the
>   local machine

I have check google and stackoverflow. 
They all say the development fabric is flawed in this area..  Any update to this Answer???

**THE ERROR**

```
=======================================================
Timestamp: 5/1/2014 5:47:36 AM
Message: HandlingInstanceID: 425ab729-f484-4846-9214-60f5f1cfb2dd
An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred and was caught.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
05/01/2014 05:47:36
Type : System.Threading.ThreadAbortException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Message : Thread was being aborted.
Source : mscorlib
Help link : 
ExceptionState : System.Web.HttpApplication+CancelModuleException
Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite : Void AbortInternal()
HResult : -2146233040
Stack Trace :    at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
   at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.AbortCurrentThread()
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse, Boolean permanent)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url)
   at master_websiteinner.btnLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Additional Info:

MachineName : RD00155D86ECB4
TimeStamp : 5/1/2014 5:47:36 AM
FullName : Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
AppDomainName : /LM/W3SVC/1505810235/ROOT-1-130433968349516357
ThreadIdentity : 
WindowsIdentity : IIS APPPOOL\testblinkawards

Category: General
Priority: 0
EventId: 100
Severity: Error
Title:blinkawards Exception Handling
Machine: RD00155D86ECB4
Application Domain: /LM/W3SVC/1505810235/ROOT-1-130433968349516357
Process Id: 3648
Process Name: D:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Win32 Thread Id: 364
Thread Name: 
Extended Properties: 
----------------------------------------
=======================================================
Timestamp: 5/1/2014 5:48:39 AM
Message: HandlingInstanceID: 0f1b4483-3d2d-4f21-addb-7b9a7ee2b430
An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred and was caught.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
05/01/2014 05:48:39
Type : System.Threading.ThreadAbortException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Message : Thread was being aborted.
Source : mscorlib
Help link : 
ExceptionState : System.Web.HttpApplication+CancelModuleException
Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite : Void AbortInternal()
HResult : -2146233040
Stack Trace :    at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
   at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.AbortCurrentThread()
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse, Boolean permanent)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url)
   at master_website.lnkAdministrator_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Additional Info:

MachineName : RD00155D86ECB4
TimeStamp : 5/1/2014 5:48:39 AM
FullName : Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
AppDomainName : /LM/W3SVC/1505810235/ROOT-1-130433968349516357
ThreadIdentity : 
WindowsIdentity : IIS APPPOOL\testblinkawards

Category: General
Priority: 0
EventId: 100
Severity: Error
Title:blinkawards Exception Handling
Machine: RD00155D86ECB4
Application Domain: /LM/W3SVC/1505810235/ROOT-1-130433968349516357
Process Id: 3648
Process Name: D:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Win32 Thread Id: 2244
Thread Name: 
Extended Properties: 
----------------------------------------
=======================================================
Timestamp: 5/1/2014 5:50:28 AM
Message: HandlingInstanceID: a730351b-e4fd-4ba2-af35-dcf7ecf9663e
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred and was caught.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
05/01/2014 05:50:28
Type : System.InvalidOperationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Message : The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.
Source : System.Data
Help link : 
Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite : Void GetDataSource(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionString, System.Data.OleDb.DataSourceWrapper ByRef)
HResult : -2146233079
Stack Trace :    at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbServicesWrapper.GetDataSource(OleDbConnectionString constr, DataSourceWrapper& datasrcWrapper)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
   at CommonFunctions.ReadExcelFile(String sSessionExtension, String FileToRead)
   at employeesinvite.ReadExcel()

Additional Info:

MachineName : RD00155D86ECB4
TimeStamp : 5/1/2014 5:50:28 AM
FullName : Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
AppDomainName : /LM/W3SVC/1505810235/ROOT-1-130433968349516357
ThreadIdentity : 
WindowsIdentity : IIS APPPOOL\testblinkawards

Category: General
Priority: 0
EventId: 100
Severity: Error
Title:blinkawards Exception Handling
Machine: RD00155D86ECB4
Application Domain: /LM/W3SVC/1505810235/ROOT-1-130433968349516357
Process Id: 3648
Process Name: D:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Win32 Thread Id: 1800
Thread Name: 
Extended Properties:
```

Comment: It works fine on my local machine... The ACEOLEDB DLL is copied in the bin of azure website too

Comment: Likely you are running in 64-bit mode on Azure.

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987080/microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-error-on-azure-cloud-service

Comment: nope I have only 32 bit machines where I developed my Web APP and uploaded on azure

Comment: Is this an Azure website or cloud service?

Comment: it is an azure website

Comment: So under the **Configure** tab you have verified that the **Platform** setting is "32-BIT"?

Comment: yes... did that too..

Comment: Mine is free website. so platform by default is set at 32 bit version

Comment: Possible this error is also because you're in a shared environment?

Comment: even on shared I have seen by default its on 32bit

Comment: I mean - that shared mode won't allow use of OleDb connection strings?

Comment: are u sure oledb wont work on share mode

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51791/discussion-between-brendan-green-and-tushar-narang)

Comment: thanks @BrendanGreen our chat has cleared many doubts I had in my mind

Comment: I did that standard mode too.. it didn't help