# 32 Bit Azure Worker Role Failed to Deploy

Tags: azure, x86, azure-worker-roles

**Why 32 bit mode?**
I have a Worker Role that must access a database delivered in MS Access format.  This requires using the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' engine.

Based on other posts I found that one possible solution is to run my Role in 32 bit mode since that engine is not available in 64 bit.

**How I Tried to Deploy 32 bit mode**
I went to my WorkerRole project and changed the Platform Target (in the project properties window) to x86.  With only that change I redeployed only to get this error:

> The server encountered an internal error. Please retry the request.

I then tried setting the toolbar build option to  x86.  I got the same error.

I have retried multiple times to no avail.  I cannot connect to the remote machine to check windows logs because it no longer exists.  As soon as I switch back to 'Any CPU' the deployment succeeds, but I cannot run my Jet engine code.

**Question**
So, how can I run my Worker Role in 32 bit mode in the current Azure Architecture (I'm assuming something changed since 2013 which is when the question I was looking at was answered).

Reference questions:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4927be5a-4652-4dbc-afe4-67ad170a6f67/microsoftjetoledb40-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine

[Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 error on Azure Cloud Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987080/microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-error-on-azure-cloud-service)

Comment: The msdn post you referenced is talking about 64-bit vs 32-bit Windows, not 64-bit vs 32-bit apps.

Comment: I thought it was relevant - am I wrong that azure roles run on 64 bit VM's?  If they do then I thought the last answer matched my situation and forcing the app into 32 bit mode would do the trick - however that isn't working here.